# How to get n-hops bidirectional in sparql

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using the following query to get `subclass of` predicate up and down for a given concept in wikidata.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?linkTo {
  { wd:Q22673982 wdt:P279* ?item } UNION { ?item wdt:P279* wd:Q22673982 }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P279 ?linkTo }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

In order to limit the hops only to 10, I extended the aforementioned query into the following.

```
PREFIX gas: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/gas#>

SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?linkTo {
  { SERVICE gas:service {
    gas:program gas:gasClass "com.bigdata.rdf.graph.analytics.SSSP" ;
                gas:in wd:Q22673982 ;
                gas:traversalDirection "Forward" ;
                gas:out ?item ;
                gas:out1 ?depth ;
                gas:maxVisited 10 ;
                gas:linkType wdt:P279 .
  } } UNION { SERVICE gas:service {
    gas:program gas:gasClass "com.bigdata.rdf.graph.analytics.SSSP" ;
                gas:in wd:Q22673982 ;
                gas:traversalDirection "Reverse" ;
                gas:out ?item ;
                gas:out1 ?depth ;
                gas:maxVisited 10 ;
                gas:linkType wdt:P279 .
  } }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P279 ?linkTo }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

I tried to do it in a similar way using DBpedia as follows.

```
SELECT * {
  { dbr:Word2vec dct:subject* ?item } UNION { ?item dct:subject* dbr:Word2vec }
  OPTIONAL { ?item dct:subject ?linkTo }
}
```

However, I get the following error: `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable '_::trans_subj_4_0' is used in subexpressions of the query but not assigned`

My question is; Is it possible to do the same in DBpedia?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: why should there be a path of `dct:subject` relations?  `dct:subject` links an item to a category, the only hierarchy is here in the categories, and this is expressed via `skos:borader` relation.

Comment: And yes, it's a (known) bug (or limitation) in Virtuoso. Obvious workaround, use two SPARQL queries.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you for the comments. Did you mean a query like this: `SELECT * {
  { dbr:Word2vec skos:broader* ?item }
  OPTIONAL { ?item skos:broader ?linkTo }
}` and `SELECT * {
  { ?item skos:broader* dbr:Word2vec}
  OPTIONAL { ?item skos:broader ?linkTo }
}` Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: yes, just send two queries to the endpoint. This should be the most obvious workaround, or not?

Comment: @AKSW Unfortunately, that did not solve my problem as I do not get anything as an results :( In wikidata (for example in the second query mentioned in the question). I was able to get 10 hops bidirectional results. As you have mentioned in the above comment I am happy to run the two queries seperately without using `union`. Do you have any suggestions to improve the existing DBpedia query? Moreover, is `wdt:P279` is equivalent to `skos:broader` in dbpedia? :)

Comment: That cannot be, I tried `select * where {dbr:Word2vec dct:subject* ?item} LIMIT 100` and it does return a non-empty result.

Comment: `wdt:P279` is subclass of for classes, and `skos:broader` is for categories. As I told you `dct:subject` related en entity to a category. `skos:broader` connects to categories. `dbr:Word2vec` is en entity and not a category. We had this discussions already in your previous questions, it has to be `dct:subject/skos:broader*` to tget the category of an entity as well as all super categories of it.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you so much. I am using the following query `select * where {dbr:Word2vec dct:subject/skos:broader{1,10} ?item} LIMIT 100` and that worked :) One last question :) If you could quickly look in to this: https://w.wiki/5wQ the output shows how terms are connected. Is it possible to do so in DBpedia? :) :)

Comment: not that I understand what this query should return, but doesn't matter: so my answer is, what prevents you from doing the same in DBpedia? I mean, just use the `skos:broader` property, or not?

Comment: @AKSW What my wikidata query returns is something similar to this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ydXfV6JkxlIDoyWiMSTaj-r6Jm8ZLIiH/view?usp=sharing When I try to do the same in DBpedia using this query `SELECT * {
  { dbr:Word2vec dct:subject/skos:broader{1,10} ?item }
  OPTIONAL { ?item dct:subject/skos:broader ?linkTo }
}` my `link to` field is empty. Do you know why this happens. Thank you :)

Comment: you still didn't understand what the data looks like and what the queries are doing, right? `dct:subject/skos:broader` would only work if the item has an edge `dct:subject` to a node which has an edge `skos:broader` to some other node. Think about it why this doesn't make sense and think one more time about my previous statement *"`dct:subject` connects an entity to a category. `skos:broader` connects a category to a category. "*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler:...* error is flagged in a couple of open issues ([#530](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/530), [#681](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/681)) on the github-hosted Virtuoso project.

As noted there, your query will likely run if you simply un-tick the **Strict checking of void variables** box on the SPARQL query form.

Comment: I am not sure weather I understood you clearly. Can you please tell me what you meant by `strict checking of void variables`

Comment: Sorry, @EmJ, I made a copy-paste error. Please re-read my edited answer, and also follow the links to the open issues and read the responses there -- particularly [the last response to #681](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/681#issuecomment-334010395).